# How can I run client side function ( JQuery / JavaScripte ) after PostBack

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic, postback

I am new to jQuery and JavaScript.

I have a Html page. There is a Form with `Method="Post"` and I have a JavaScript function.

On the server side I use ASP classic.

I need to `post` my form with my `Submit Button` and after submit and load my page, Run a JavaScript method.

This is a sample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>..........</title>
    <style>
       ...........
    </style>
<script>
    function initialize() {
    .....
    }
</script>
<body>
    <div style="height:250px">
        <form id="form1" runat="server" method="Post">

            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
            <br>
            First name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname">
            <br>
            Last name:<br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Ok" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need after `PostBack` run `initialize` method

I use this JQuery but it dose not work.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "ISPostBack.html",
            context: document.body
        }).done(function () {
            initialize();
        });
    });

</script>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Well you can use jQuery for pretty much everything. You can serialize your form, use an ajax `POST`, and then handle the callbacks via `.done` or `.fail` (or `.success`)

Comment: @Invent-Animate : How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can look this https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  use ajax to request

Comment: Can you tell me who can I de this exactly ?